# How to stored the (Kafka) logs in to Database(Cassandra or Hive)?

Tags: apache-kafka

How to stored the logs
which is from producer to consumer into Database
I follow below step after Download the 0.9.0.0 release and un-tar it.

1. `$ bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties &`
2. `$ bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties`
3. `$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic fast-messages`

$ `bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic summary-markers`

4. `$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181`
5. `$ cd .. $ mvn package`
6. Run the  producer
7. Start the  consumer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Download the 0.9.0.0 release and un-tar it.

That is a very old version of Kafka... All the steps you've used work the exact same on newer versions, and will likely be more stable.

---

Kafka doesn't store its data (logs) in a database.

---

If you want to send data that is produced to Kafka into another system, then the included tool (as of Kafka 0.10) is called [**Kafka Connect**](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect), and you can find Connectors that already exist for HDFS/Hive as well as Cassandra.

But you're welcome to write any Consumer to write to these systems on your own, Kafka just doesn't bundle this out of the box.